# Java equals method regarding null in array

Tags: java, arrays, null, equals

In the code fragment below I was told that in the if statement, the position of this.item[i] and item cannot be swapped, because there might be a null in the item[i] array. I don't understand why...

what I was told works: if(this.item[i].equals(item))
what I was told doesn't work: if(item.equals(this.item[i]))

```
public boolean contains(Object item){
    for(int i = 0; i < this.numItems; i ++)
        if(this.item[i].equals(item))
            return true; 
        }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: You should specify what language this is.

Comment: This question needs to be more explicit. Youre talking about swapping array indices, null indices and you put a code snippet of comparing indices. None of those things are related to each other, so nobody knows what youre talking about or asking. Please reword your question.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you should cast item to the class that item is. You are comparing the raw object. So if your class is Item.class

```
if (item instanceof Item)
{
    Item i = (Item)item; //where item is the object passed to the method.
}
```

Also if item[i] is null, you cant use the `equals` method on it. Try doing a null check then using `equals` like so:

```
if (item != null && item instanceof Item)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
    {
        Item castedItem = (Item)item;
        if (item[i] != null && item[i] instanceof Item && item[i].equals(castItem))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```